# Filter and combine fields from 2 arrays with ES6 JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have 2 arrays, one of pizza details and the other is an order state. The `id` field is what links them. So in this example, the order has 2 x Pepperoni and 3 x Margarita.

```
const pizzaContent = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: 'Pepperoni',
    price: 20,
    hot: true,
    stockQuantity: 3
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Margarita',
    price: 25,
    stockQuantity: 3
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Hawaiian',
    price: 15,
    stockQuantity: 0
  }
];

const orders = [{
  id: 0,
  quantity: 2
},{
  id: 1,
  quantity: 3
}];
```

I'm trying to create a new array which has the quantity from `orders` and the fields from `pizzaContent`. Any pizzas which aren't in the order shouldn't be part of this array.

I've gotten close with the following:

```
const pizzasInOrder = this.props.orders.map(order => {
  return (
    {
      quantity: order.quantity,
      pizza: this.props.pizzas.find(pizza => {
        return (
          order.id === pizza.id
        );
      })
    }
  )
});
```

However, the result is:

```
pizzasInOrder = [
  {
    pizza: {id: 0, name: "Pepperoni", price: 20, hot: true, stockQuantity: 3}, 
    quantity:2
  },
  { 
    pizza: {id: 1, name: "Margarita", price: 25, stockQuantity: 3}, 
    quantity:3 
  }
]
```

But what I need is:

```
pizzasInOrder = [
  {
    id: 0, name: "Pepperoni", price: 20, hot: true, stockQuantity: 3, quantity: 2
  },
  { 
    id: 1, name: "Margarita", price: 25, stockQuantity: 3, quantity: 3 
  }
]
```

Comment: If the ids always match with no holes then just sort the two on the id and loop over using the same index to get matching records. Otherwise hash on the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.assign()` to merge objects into one.

example..

```js
const pizzaContent = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: 'Peperoni',
    price: 20,
    hot: true,
    stockQuantity: 3
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Margarita',
    price: 25,
    stockQuantity: 3
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Hawian',
    price: 15,
    stockQuantity: 0
  }
];

const orders = [{
  id: 0,
  quantity: 2
},{
  id: 1,
  quantity: 3
}];

let pizzasInOrder = orders.map((order) => {
  return Object.assign(order, 
    pizzaContent.find(pizza => order.id === pizza.id));
});

console.log(pizzasInOrder);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Object.assign and no extra keys

```
const pizzasInOrder = this.props.orders.map(order => 
    Object.assign({quantity: order.quantity}, 
        this.props.pizzas.find(pizza => order.id === pizza.id))        
);
```